# Can't get fullcalendar to load events based on JSON

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying fullcalendar for the first time and I'm unable to make it display any events based on a JSON string that the server side generates.  I fully expected that once the calendar received the JSON string that the blue events would appear on the calendar.  Not so.  I've checked and confirmed that the JSON string is arriving in firebug from the server. So, I'm sitting here thinking, "What gives?".  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Appointment Service - Calendar View</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../media/css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="../media/css/fullcalendar.print.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../media/css/site.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({       
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today,prev,next'
    },
    defaultDate: '2017-01-11',
    editable: true,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: {
        url: '/JAppoint/CalendarViewServlet',
        error: function() {
            $('#script-warning').show();
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("successful: You can now do your stuff here. You dont need ajax. Full Calendar will do the ajax call OK? ");   
        }
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<style> 

#script-warning {
    display: none;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}

#loading {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

#calendar {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "interface">

<div class="leftjustify">Calendar View</div><div class="rightjustify"><a id="logoutlink" href="../LogoutServlet">logout</a></div>    
<div id='script-warning'>
    <code>/JAppoint/CalendarViewServlet</code> must be running.
</div>
<div id='loading'>loading...</div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":"","title":"All Day Event","start":"2016-01-03","end":"","url":""},{"id":"","title":"Nova Dental","start":"2016-01-06 13:00","end":"2016-01-06 14:00","url":""},{"id":"","title":"Conference","start":"2016-01-07 09:30","end":"2016-01-07 11:30","url":""},{"id":"","title":"MHTC","start":"2016-01-10 07:00","end":"2016-01-10 19:00","url":""},{"id":"","title":"MHTC","start":"2016-01-11 19:00","end":"2016-01-12 07:00","url":""},{"id":"","title":"MHTC","start":"2016-01-12 19:00","end":"2016-01-13 07:00","url":""},{"id":"","title":"meeting","start":"2016-01-20 08:30","end":"2016-01-20 09:30","url":""}]
```

Comment: they are all dated 2016 and your calendar starts from 2017 ?

Comment: Aaugh!!! Of course! It had to be that.  Thanks.  That did it.